# How to format ASP.NET grid view header text using html?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

If in the html table header, I would use:

```
<th class="titleclass" width="200"><span>Header Text</span> <sup><a href="#link"><span style="font-size: 12px">1</span></a></sup></th>
```

How can I use the same header text in bound field of asp.net gridview. I tried the following:

```
<asp:boundcolumn 
    visible="True" 
    datafield="Column1" 
    headertext="<span>Header Text</span> <sup><a href='#link'><span style='font-size: 12px'>1</span></a></sup>" 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="titleclass">
    <itemstyle horizontalalign="Left"></itemstyle>
</asp:boundcolumn>
```

This is not working. It says "**There is not source available for the current location**" and the style for my header text is not applied (but the style for the superfix number 1 is applied). Any thoughts?

Comment: Why must it be a BoundColumn versus a TemplateColumn?

Comment: What is the HTML rendered to the page for the `tr` & `th` tags? And what says "There is not source available for the current location", that sounds like a binding problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your field to Template: 'Edit Columns - Select needed field - Convert to Template'

Edit the header template as desired.

Refer to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

Comment: I complete forgot about template columns. Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HeaderStyle Property of the gridview.

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<HeaderStyle CssClass="titleclass"/>
.
.
.`

Or you can do it from within your ASP.NET code,

```
GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderStyle.CssClass = "titleClass";
```

Hope this helps